# Internet Explorer 8 - Maximum number of links in the Favorites Bar

Tags: bookmarks, internet-explorer-8

I have a user who used to use the Links Bar in previous versions of Internet Explorer.  When he upgraded to IE8, he now has a ton of links in his Favorites Bar since they've done away with the Links Bar.  Now when he clicks on the double arrows to access the list of links (since they won't all fit on the Favorites Bar), Internet Explorer locks up as if it cannot process that many links in the Favorites Bar.  Does anyone know if there is a limit as to the number of links you can keep in the Favorites Bar?

In addition, if the user adds a new link to the Favorites Bar, the double arrow dropdown works like a charm, but the next time he opens an IE8 window, it goes back to not working correctly.

I know telling him to use the Favorites List and clean up his Favorites Bar would be ideal, but I would think that Internet Explorer should be able to handle any number of links, no?  Otherwise, why would they build in the double arrow button/feature...

Has anyone else had this problem?  Is it an IE8 bug?

Comment: How many links are we talking about?  I suspect the number is high enough that he's not going to get a lot of sympathy...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  He has a lot organized into folders, but also has another 50 or so as singles.  I would guess that we're talking in the realm of 110 links.

Answer (score 0):

I have an IE8 machine and just saved 100 links to this question on the bar (good ol' copy and paste).

I can scroll backwards and forwards quite happily.

Either your user needs to reinstall IE, or his machine is not powerful enough to handle a relatively small amount of data.